# Auto-crop width, not height

Tags: images, cropping

I need images to be auto-cropped if they are too wide only. Basically like this:

[image: Crop-visualization]

I'm using it for a fullscreen slider, where too wide images gets stretched. Cropping obviously is the best of two evils.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress cant do it alone. You need a script called Timthumb.php to do it.  This is really simple to use. Check it out: https://code.google.com/p/timthumb/

And the best: wordpress will not store multiple versions of your images when crop. It will be done by the script on demand.